# Ubuntu 16.04.1 mod_mono won't install

Tags: c#, apache2, mono

I was having some issue with my server so I decided to fully un-install Mono and re-install it. Big error. It won't re-install and the server is broken until I fix it.

First, I un-installed everything mono-related.

Then, I followed these instructions to install on Ubuntu 16.04.1
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

I confirm the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list contains

```
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main
```

I then type "apt-get install mono-complete"

Then apache2 fails to reload. After digging, it becomes clear there is no trace of mod_mono. If I look in /etc/apache2/mods-available/, mod_mono isn't there.

Why is mod_mono failing to install, and how can I install it? Thanks!

As a side note, I also tried reinstalling the default Ubuntu version without the Xamarin repository, and it also failed to install mod_mono.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ModMono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link SushiHangover.

This solved the problem:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-mono
```

Additionally, httpd.conf contained

```
#MonoAutoApplication enabled
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

<IfModule fcgid_module>
  <FilesMatch ".(aspx|axd|asmx|ashx|asax|ascx|soap|rem|axd|cs|config|Config|dll)$>
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .aspx
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .asmx
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .ashx
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .asax
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .ascx
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .soap
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .rem
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .axd
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .cs
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .config
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .Config
    FCGIWrapper /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 .dll
    Options +ExecCGI
 </FilesMatch>

 FcgidInitialEnv MONO_FCGI_APPCONFIGDIR /etc/mono-fastcgi
 FcgidMaxRequestLen 204800000
</IfModule>
```

It complained about being unable to find /usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4. Not sure why it was configured that way, but I commented the whole lower section and uncommented MonoAutoApplication and it's now working.